# Is there any effective way to compress large string in javascript before sending it to the server and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a google chrome extension currently in which I have to take screenshot of the page and send it to our server , but the problem is the string generated after taking the screenshot is just too large and it becomes a bit difficult to send it through get request. 
So is there any effective way/algorithm/API in javascript to compress and decompress the same ? 
 
This is how I am taking screenshots in google chrome !

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUrl){
        // console.log(dataUrl); 
});
```

I have tried using some API available on github (https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) but couldn't get anything .So could you please guide me for the same ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is the goal to capture an image or the actual page markup?

Comment: I want to capture the current window which I am working on and send it to the server .

Comment: In `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` you can select JPEG format with a low quality to reduce the size.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). we can't help if you dont show and explain what you tried that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use GET requests to upload data. This is what POST (or PUT) requests are for.

Comment: Still the size of the string is too large .Won't it be a problem to send such a large string ?

Comment: Not at all. Web sites routinely use POST requests for large file uploads.

Comment: Could you guide me how can I send a javascript object of size ~ 1 mb to a server which necessarily don't share the same domain ?